# Matrix associated to a linear transformation given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

$2$ and $0$ are eigenvalues of  $\mathbf{T }: \mathbb{ R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{ R}^3$ $B=\left\{ \vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w} \right\}$ is a basis for the transformation and 
 $$E_{2}= Gen\left\{\vec{u}=(1,1,-1)^{T},   \vec{v}=(0,1,-1)^T \right\}$$  $$E_{0}= Gen\left\{\vec{w}=(1,0,-1)^{T}\right\}$$

Then P (The matrix composed by the eigenvectors) is $P=\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0 &1 \\ 
 1&1  &0 \\ 
 -1& -1 &-1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1 &1 \\ 
 -1&0  &1 \\ 
 0& -1 &-1 
\end{pmatrix}$ also, by the information given $D=\begin{pmatrix}
 2& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&2  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, I have to find the the matrix associated to the transformation on the basis $B$. I know that $\mathbf{T }(\vec{v})=\lambda(\vec{v})$ but I'm not quite sure of how to proceed.

Comment: $P^{-1}$ above is off by a factor of $\frac 12$  and yes $A = PDP^{-1}$ is your transformation in the standard basis.